# which mod_perl for windows 7 x86, apache 2.2.25, perl 5.16?

Tags: perl, apache

the title perty much says it all.  running;
windows 7 on x86 mother board, with apache 2.2.25 and perl 5.16.
I can't seem to find aggrenment on witch mod_perl to use.  AND,
from the docs i've seen the problem will be getting it and 
configuring. pointers of detailed instructions will be best.

and i see another problem coming before i get there and i've looked around.

how to get windows 7 iis permission to run .cgi and .pl script.

what i've read start will, run inetmgr.exe..  when i try to run inetmgr.exe the system
tell me 'can't find', are the docs wrong, my windows admin file broken ???

please respond to grumpyoldphuker@gmail.com.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Apache and mod_perl if you just need to run CGI scripts under IIS on Windows. Perl will be able to do that by itself, as long as you have IIS configured to run CGI scripts correctly.

Otherwise, you might want to take a look at http://plackperl.org/ instead, for the "modern" way to run Perl-based web applications. You can likely use IIS as a front-end proxy in front of your Plack server process.